# The structure "une de ces", as in "vous m'avez fichu une de ces frousses !": How strong does it sound?

Tags: expressions

> Vous m'avez fichu **une de ces frousses** !
>
> {compared to}: Vous m'avez fichu **une frousse bleue** !
>
> {compared to}: Vous m'avez fichu **la frousse**  !

I use this "une de ces" structure when saying, for instance, "tirer une de ces têtes", but I have always wondered which of the three is considered strongest in tone?

Incidentally, what other verbs can I use in  saying the following?

> Vous m'avez **fichu**/**fiché**/**collé**/**flanqué**/**donné** une de ces frousses !

Comment: The first two are more emphatic but also less absolute. So it's hard to say which is the “strongest”. *Fichu* and *fiché* are both softened versions of *foutu*. But I see you've already gathered a nice list.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Conjugation tables list "fiché" as the Participe Passé of "ficher/fiche", but doctors around me seem to nearly always use "fichu" instead. Is it related to a regional difference or something?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20375/quest-ce-que-jen-ai-%c3%a0-fiche-correct-or-not

Answer (score 3):

The first one would be the strongest in this case. The use of "une/un de ces" heavily relies on the "ces" part:

> Vous m'avez fichu une de **ces** frousses !

Even though the translation for this one would be "You scared me to death", it is much easier to explain the importance of "ces" with a more gross, literal translation: "You gave me one of **those** fears !"

"ces" and "those" translate the same feeling in this case: they mean that the "frousse" we're talking about isn't just a random "frousse", but that it belongs to a certain category of "frousses". Here, we are implying that it is, indeed, the strongest category of "frousses".