# Apparente erreur dans l'écriture de l'infinitif « ficher »

Tags: usage, verbes, orthographe, infinitif, évolution

> Extrait d'un roman de Georges Bernanos, *Le Journal d'un curé de campagne*
>
> Dieu sait que je voudrais donner pour
> rien, avec mon temps et ma peine, les tapis de coton, les draperies rongées des mites, et les cierges de suif payés très cher au fournisseur de Son Excellence, mais qui s’effondrent dès qu’on les allume, avec un bruit de poêle à
> frire. Seulement les tarifs sont les tarifs : que puis-je ?
> – Vous devriez fiche le bonhomme à la porte, m’a-t-il
> dit. Et, comme je protestais :
> – Le fiche dehors, parfaitement ! D’ailleurs, je le connais, votre Dumonchel : le vieux a de quoi... Sa défunte femme était deux fois plus riche que lui, – juste qu’il l’enterre proprement !

L'occurrence du premier « fiche » ne détourne pas de la lecture bien longtemps, on pense rapidement à une erreur de mise page ; la raison est toute simple : on attend un infinitif après « devoir » et donc il faudrait « Vous devriez ficher ». Cependant, une récidive dans la phrase suivante vient vite détruire l'idée d'avoir aplani la difficulté. C'est une phrase sans sujet, il lui faut bien un verbe, le seul candidat pour cette fonction ne pouvant être que « fiche » et ce n'est toujours pas un infinitif.

Chose bizarre lorsqu'on commence à vérifier des références, on trouve que certains parlent du verbe « [se fiche](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/fiche.html) » et pas du tout de « se ficher », alors que le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fiche/3) n'a que « ficher » dans ses entrées principales. En examinant les sous entrées on s'aperçoit que l'infinitif est bien « fiche » dans beaucoup de cas. Comment expliquer que cette anomalie ait été acceptée et non rejetée de façon à ce que les désinences soient conformes à l'usage (Par exemple le TLFi mentionne « ficher » en tant qu'entrée et « fiche » n'est qu'un second choix dans le corps de cette entrée) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Qu'est-ce que j'en ai à fiche" : correct or not?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20375/quest-ce-que-jen-ai-%c3%a0-fiche-correct-or-not)

Comment: @jlliagre Vous ne voyez pas que ça n'apporte pas de réponse à cette question ? Non, il n'y a pas de réponse.

Comment: La réponse d'Eau qui dort est la meilleure qu'on puisse donner à cette question.

Comment: C'est vrai qu'il dit qu'il pourrait y avoir eu une influence de « foutu » qui aurait incité certain à utiliser « fichu », mais ça ce n'est pas ce qu'on lui demande, c'est en plus ; ce qu'on lui demande c'est si la forme « fiche » pour l'infinitif est correcte, et il répond qu'elle l'est. Ma question n'est pas tellement pourquoi « fiche » a été choisi mais pourquoi on a toléré qu'il soit choisi, comment ça se fait que personne n'ait pu ou voulu rectifier cela. Il ne faut pas oublier qu'au TLFi, si dans le corps de l'entrée on mentionne « fiche », c'est très souvent en tant que second choix.

Comment: Il n'est pas question de tolérance, on adopte ou pas les choses parce que c'est la norme de fait, parce que les autres le disent et que ça nous va, pas parce que c'est logique ou que l'Académie ou autres souhaiteraient autrement. L'infinitif *fiche* a probablement commencé comme une mode, un trait d'humour qui a plu et s'est imposé au XIXe siècle puis au XXe.

Comment: @LPH pouvez-vous changer la question et son titre par quelque chose comme "comment est apparu l'emploi de l'infinitif *fiche* ?" puisque cela semble être votre question en définitive ? Tel quelle, la Q parait confuse et ressemble en effet énormément à celle déjà existante pointée par jiliagre.

Comment: Je peux faire un changement mais pas celui-là.

Comment: Mais du coup quelle raison de ne pas voter Duplicate ? Je ne comprends pas...

Comment: @guillaume31 La question mentionnée par user jlliagre n'est que la demande de vérification que la forme « fiche » pour l'infinitif est correcte. Dans la réponse qui donne cette confirmation on a en bonus une hypothèse étymologique sur la création de « fichu » (assez probablement de « foutu »), mais ce n'est toujours pas une réponse à ma question, même si ça la concerne de près.

Comment: @LPH l'entrée dans le TLFI n'est pas un second choix mais l'entrée principale pour ce sens du mot "ficher". L'infinitif "fiche" apparait dès le I.-A. de cet emploi.

Comment: Désolé mais je ne comprends toujours pas la différence entre votre question et celle de jiliagre... surtout avec ce titre qui n'est pas une question

Comment: @guillaume31 Il y a une petite erreur : c'est « ficher » qui apparait souvent en seconde position (Ne pas en fiche/ficher une datte, une rame, une secousse) ; cependant l'entrée est « FICHER³ ». La question n'est pas pourquoi les gens ont choisi « fiche » mais pourquoi les gens conscient des usages et responsables de leur préservation ont toléré qu'un choix soit fait qui allait contre l'usage établi pour les verbes du premier groupe ; est-ce par exemple parce qu'ils auraient été débordé du fait du nombre de publications déjà sorties lorsqu'ils ont constaté le problème (qu'une possibilité)?

Comment: @LPH Non, c'est à mon avis un glissement dans le langage oral vers une forme plus courte, à la prononciation plus aisée et plus proche de "foutre" tout en restant polie. Mais peut-être qu'un linguiste de passage le confirmera (s'il ou elle ne s'en tient pas à la question originelle et lit les commentaires jusqu'ici ...)

Comment: @guillaume31 Un linguiste dont il n'y a aucune raison de se méfier a déjà donné son avis et il s'agit précisément d'Eau qui dort.

Comment: Sa réponse à la question posée par LPH: *It looks like the 19th century innovators of fiche interpreted foutre as a stem /futR/ + a suffix /ə/, and backformed fiche (/fiʃ/ + /ə/) from it.*

Comment: @jiliagre et je suis tout enclin à le croire (même si sa réponse n'est pas formelle).

Answer (score 6):

> Comment expliquer cette anomalie ?

Le verbe ***fiche*** ne comporte pas de ***R*** à l'infinitif quand il est utilisé comme euphémisme pour ***foutre***.

Une hypothèse serait de dire que cet infinitif singulier permet de marquer la distinction avec les deux autres verbe ***ficher*** (planter et mettre sur fiche).

Une autre serait une proximité phonétique plus grande avec ***foutre***, qui comme ***fiche*** n'a qu'une syllabe et se termine par un ***E*** muet.

Une troisième serait éventuellement l'évitement d'une confusion phonétique entre l'hypothétique ***rien à ficher*** et ***rien affiché***.

Une quatrième serait un parler régional qui se serait imposé.

On pourrait encore sûrement formuler d'autres hypothèses, mais la vraie raison pour laquelle on dit ***rien à fiche*** est justement que ça se dit comme ça.

Une langue vivante n'est pas comme les mathématiques, quelque chose qu'on apprend en suivant des règles rationnelles et qui se tiennent. Un locuteur natif apprend une langue simplement en répétant et extrapolant ce qu'il a entendu. L'usage s'impose à la grammaire, pas la logique.

https://bescherelle.ca/verbe-se-fiche/

Comment: Non, ce n'est pas aussi strict que les mathématiques, mais quand même, on parle tous à peu près de la même façon parce qu'un système ne cesse pas de nous rappeler des normes, des règles qui sont assez rigoureuses. Une question plus précise serait « Comment cette forme a-t-elle échappé aux forces d'uniformisation habituelles ? ».

Comment: L'usage s'impose au système et non l'inverse, sinon, on parlerait encore la bas-latin.

Comment: Mais non, mais non, il n'est pas question de votre principe unique : on le voit très bien actuellement, c'est le système qui décide que l'on ne dit plus les mots « auteur », « professeur », etc. en parlant d'un auteur femme, etc., mais « autrice », « professeure » etc., et les gens ont commencé  tout d'un coup  à ne plus parler comme ils le faisaient et ont changé leur langue pour parler exactement comme cela leur a été indiqué.

Comment: Il n'existe pas de « forces d'uniformisation habituelles ». Les évolutions peuvent aller dans un sens d'uniformisation ou au contraire de diversification. Ce fameux verbe *ficher* n'est rien d'autre qu'une évolution du verbe *fixer*, tout le contraire d'une uniformisation donc.

Comment: Rien ne se passe « tout d'un coup », les évolutions suivent les lois de la sélection naturelle et sont le plus souvent lentes. Elles peuvent avoir des origines diverses, mais le «  système » comme tu dis, ne peut rien imposer. Toutes sortes de sources et de références, des films, des pièces de théâtre, des livres, des humoristes, des hommes politiques, des locuteurs d'autres langues, etc. peuvent être à l'origine d'une évolution potentielle mais c'est l'usage qui a toujours le dernier mot.

Comment: Le verbe *fiche* et sont participe passé *fichu* sont d'ailleurs d'un usage ancien (*fichu* est déjà présent dans le premier dictionnaire de l'Académie de 1694), *rien à fiche* est lui en perte de vitesse, supplanté soit pas *rien à faire* soit par *rien à foutre*. Difficile de parler de nouveauté à son sujet.

Comment: Bien sûr que si : tout d'un coup, j'ai pu constater que des personnes qui se disaient « professeur » étaient maintenant « professeur**e** » et que les nouveaux noms apparaissaient dans les articles de presse et ailleurs; il y a bien des forces d'uniformisation. Dans ce cas, c'est la décision de l'Académie qui lancé le changement avec leur changement officiel d'attitude sur les noms de fonction. Il y a d'autres entités qui sont des agents de cette force.

Comment: L'apparition d'un nouveau mot est forcément instantanée, même si elle peut se produire à des endroits et à des moments différents mais son adoption n'est jamais instantanée. C'est un processus lent et aléatoire. *Professeure* est apparu au moins en 1940 et n'est pas encore adopté partout, il n'y a rien là d'instantané. Certaines circonstances peuvent rendre l'adoption d'un nouveau mot très rapide, comme par exemple *covid* qui s'est imposé en quelques jours/semaines. C'est néanmoins l'usage qui impose le masculin en France alors que le « système » souhaiterait le féminin.

Comment: Le masculin n'est plus imposé ; c'est tout le contraire, depuis la décision de l'académie c'est un mot de forme féminine qui est imposé, et c'est d'origine toute récente : [2019](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/actualites/la-feminisation-des-noms-de-metiers-et-de-fonctions)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145118/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lph).

Answer (score 4):

Par la prémisse « Extrait d'un roman de Georges Bernanos, Le Journal d'un curé de campagne », j'en comprends que les protagonistes vivent à la campagne.

Ne serait-ce pas là la volonté de l'auteur de répercuter ce contexte dans leurs paroles ? Je ne connais pas le roman, mais j'ai entendu à la campagne de tels propos de la forme « faudra le fiche ailleurs ».  Une façon détournée de ne pas utiliser « foutre » comme il est d'usage au Québec de transformer les mots de sacre par des supplétifs. Et si on remplace le premier par le deuxième, ça sonne bien plus commun, n'est-il pas ?

C'est d'ailleurs la première explication du TLFi : Fam., supplétif euphémique de foutre.

Comment: La question est posée dans le but de savoir pourquoi il existe un verbe du [premier groupe,  « ficher », qui n'a pas un, mais deux infinitifs ; je ne connais cette particularité pour aucun autre verbe du premier groupe.

Comment: @LPH Justement, c'est l'exception qui confirme la règle. Dans cette acception, c'est un verbe à cheval sur les premier et troisième groupes. On dit *Rien à fiche*, je n'ai jamais entendu *Rien à ficher*.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne vois pas d'explication dans cette réponse ; elle ne donne pas la raison pour l'anomalie ; c'est une réponse hors sujet ; ce qui est demandé c'est comment cette catégorie ambigüe s'explique ; y-a-t-il d'autres cas de verbes comme celui-ci ? « L'exception qui confirme la règle  » ne signifie rien pour moi.

Comment: Je ne vois pas d'autre verbe que celui-là. La raison de cet infinitif irrégulier est qu'il ne s'agit pas vraiment du verbe *ficher* mais d'un euphémisme pour *foutre*, et qu'on ne dit pas *J'en ai rien à foutrer*.

Comment: *Tous les verbes français contiennent la lettre r à l'infinitif quelle que soit la terminaison : -er, -ir, -oir, -re... **sauf un qui confirme la règle** : fiche. Ce verbe familier vient de ficher et signifie faire. On le retrouve à l'infinitif dans l'expression "Rien à fiche". Et il n'a pas de r !*  [Le Figaro](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/fiche_pronominal.html)

Answer (score 3):

### Parce que c'est comme cela que les gens parlent

Votre question porte bien sur savoir pourquoi un tel infinitif bizarre est utilisé. La réponse est la même que pour toutes les questions portant sur le pourquoi de telle ou telle particularité grammaticale: les gens parlent ainsi.

Quant à savoir pourquoi les gens parlent ainsi, d'autres ont déjà répondu: la formulation avec "foutre" est très populaire mais comme elle est très vulgaire certaines préfèrent lui substituer l'euphémisme "fiche", les deux signifiant dans cet usage "faire" ou parfois "mettre" voire "désintéresser" (comme dans "je m'en fiche").

Je n'ai pas trouvé de source officielle sur l'origine étymologique de cet euphémisme, mais j'ai une hypothèse qui me semble tenir: le participe passé de "foutre" est "foutu", et en tant qu'adjectif il signifie "qui ne peut plus fonctionner". C'est le même sens pour "fichu", le participe de "fiche" (mais pas de "ficher", dont le participe est "fiché"). Mon hypothèse est donc que le verbe "fiche" est une extrapolation de l'adjectif "fichu" en tant que participe passé.

Comment: On m'aurait dit que jusqu'à une certaine période dans le passé les mécanismes institutionnels  sont arrivés à préserver la parfaite uniformité de forme des verbes, et il la préservent encore presque parfaitement, mais qu'à partir de cette période ils ont commencé à ne plus opérer de cette façon (apparition de « ficher ») , je serais devenu curieux. On a changé comment les gens parlent tout au cours des siècles. Un rapprochement entre « fichu » et « foutu » serait convainquant dans l'explication de pourquoi les gens parlent comme ils le font, mais vous ne faites pas ce rapprochement.

Comment: @LPH Je ne comprends pas ce que vous dites. Ce ne sont jamais les "mécanismes institutionnels" qui font une langue, mais ses locuteurs. Parfois une institution peut suggérer un usage, mais tant que les locuteurs ne l'ont pas adopté ça ne deviendra pas une règle de ce langage.

Comment: On ne peut pas nier que les locuteurs d'une langue participent à son élaboration, mais dire cela consiste à faire une généralisation sans borne qui n'est pas utile ; la vaste majorité des locuteurs n'apportent rien à la langue et ce n'est qu'une très petite minorité qui y contribue et comprend ses rouages, les linguistes, les intellectuels, les enseignants ; eux seuls sont capable de juger de la valeur d'un tour ou d'un principe de grammaire, eux seuls possèdent la connaissance de la base technique sur laquelle repose l'édifice. Les mécanismes sont multiples ; ils fonctionnent (1/3)

Comment: à travers des organismes, et des individus qui occuppent des positions privilégiées, l'Académie (qui décide de ce qu'il faut et ne faut pas dire), le gouvernement qui entre autres choses fait des décrets sur la langue et fournit des listes de termes nouveaux reconnus, les  académies régionales qui peuvent dicter certains programmes ([ex.](https://www.ac-montpellier.fr/langues-et-cultures-regionales-124969) et orienter la langue, les maisons de publications qui ont leur mot à dire sur ce qu'elles proposent au public, les écrivains eux-mêmes, qui ont  (2/3)

Comment: une grande influence sur le public, les enseignants, qui tendent à enseigner ce en quoi ils croient ;  tout cela et plus encore constitue des mécanismes qui contribuent à façonner la langue. Ils fonctionnent tous essentiellement à travers des institutions. (3/3)

Comment: @LPH Non. Pour prendre l'exemple de l'Académie: elle ne comporte personne qui "comprenne les rouages" de la langue (zéro linguistes, eh oui, et il suffit de regarder ce qu'ils produisent pour se rendre compte que n'importe qui avec du temps pour lui ferait un aussi bon travail). Elle ne décide de rien (elle émet des avis, en général peu éclairés, et seuls ceux que ça amuse les suivent). Cette vision élitiste de l'évolution d'une langue est fausse, en plus d'être méprisante.

Comment: La grammaire n'est-elle pas un recueil d'une partie des rouages de la Langue ? N'existe-t-il pas une [grammaire de l'Académie](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-grammaire-de-lacademie-francaise) ?  Personne à l'Académie ne connaitrait cette grammaire et personne n'aurait d'avis sur cette grammaire ? Je ne crois pas ça. Il y a de nombreuses personnes dans le monde qui parlent une langue entièrement faite par des spécialistes, l'espéranto, et personne ne parle d'élitisme. Il n'est question que de faits ; rapporter ces faits n'a rien à voir avec le mépris. Vos accusations d'élitisme (1/3)

Comment: et encore plus, de mépris, sont entièrement gratuites. D'ailleurs, vous ne daigneriez même pas nous expliquer en quoi consiste votre élitisme, vous savez pertinemment que ça ne signifie rien dans ce contexte, ce n'est qu'un croquemitaine que vous utilisez pour rallier le monde à vos opinions.  Lorsque l'Académie,  si peu efficace soit-elle, émet une prescription "Dire et pas dire", elle prend une décision, au même titre qu'une équipe de lexicographes qui rédige un dictionnaire. Faut-il vous rappeler que ces lexicographes ne sont pas n'importe qui dans la société mais des personnes  (2/3)

Comment: spécialement formées à la fin de cette rédaction, des experts, eux même membres d'une élite intellectuelle qui prend des décisions, et non des   « locuteurs » comme vous espérez nous le faire croire, et que vos « locuteurs » ne rédigent jamais un dictionnaire ? (3/3)

Answer (score 2):

"fiche" est dans ce sens l’infinitif de "ficher" utilisé comme **synonyme de "foutre"** qui est considéré comme plutôt inconvenant..
*Ce type d'infinitif est effectivement très particulier.*

Exemples:

> Comment vous ne savez pas ? La mère Cloutet vient de se fiche dans le canal avec ses deux gosses ; on l’a retirée encore
> vivante et c’est une grande chance, car elle est enceinte, mais les
> deux pauv’ gosses sont noyés.
> (Léon Frapié, La maternelle, Librairie Universelle, 1908)
>
> Voilà au moins cinq mois que l’on n’avait pas vu le père Bouzille se
> fiche à l’eau !…
> (Pierre Souvestre et Marcel Allain, Les Amours d’un prince, 1912, chapitre XXVI)

> Ah ! non, non, pas ma sonate ! cria Mme Verdurin, je n’ai pas envie à force de pleurer de me fiche un rhume de cerveau avec névralgies faciales, comme la dernière fois.
> (Marcel Proust, Un amour de Swann, 1913, réédition Le Livre de Poche, page 8)

> Rappelez-vous ce que raconte bonne-maman, reprit Phili. Son attitude lorsqu’il a perdu une petite fille… Il avait l’air de s’en fiche… Il n’a jamais mis les pieds au cimetière…
> (François Mauriac, Le Nœud de vipères, Grasset, 1933, réédition Le Livre de Poche, page 101)

> Si je veux un ouistiti, je l’aurai, le ouistiti ! Et si ça me plaît d’élever des vipères pour vous les fiche dans vos lits…
> (François Mauriac, Le drôle, 1933 ; Gedalge, 1956, page 42)

> J’avais seize ans à l’époque, et je n’ai plus pensé qu’à une seule chose : comment fiche le camp ?
> (Kai Hermann et Horst Rieck, Moi, Christiane F., 13 ans, droguée, prostituée…, 1978. Traduit de l’allemand par Léa Marcou, 1981, page 67)

Je n'ai pas trouvé d'explication à cet infinitif "fiche" et non "ficher".

Le commentaire suivant de [Henri Theureau](https://fr.quora.com/Quelle-est-la-diff%C3%A9rence-entre-je-m-en-fiche-et-je-m-en-fous) donne queques petites informations , mais ne répond pas à la question.

> Je m’en fiche est, à l’origine, un euphémisme, une version édulcorée
> de Je m’en fous. De la même façon qu’on dit “mince!” au lieu de dire
> “merde !”, on dit (ou on disait) “je m’en fiche” pour, précisément, ne
> pas dire “je m’en fous”, qui est (était) assez grossier à une époque.
> En effet, le verbe foutre était l’équivalent du verbe fuck en anglais.
>
> De la même façon, l’exclamation “fichtre !” était un euphémisme pour
> l’exclamation “foutre !” (fuck! ou fuck it!), qui avait de nombreuses
> variantes comme foutredieu ou foutrebleu (pour éviter le blasphème
> avec “dieu”), et des dérivations comme foutrement/fichtrement
> (extremely), foutu (ruined), foutriquet (nincompoop). Sur le modèle de
> “foutu”, le verbe “ficher”, qui devrait faire “fiché” au participe
> passé, fait en fait “fichu”: Qui est-ce qui m’a fichu un pareil
> foutriquet ? (Who the hell sent me such a frigging bugger ?)

Comment: La collection d'exemples que vous fournissez est utile dans la confirmation du fait que ce verbe est bizarre, mais ne constitue pas une raison pour cette anomalie. C'est un verbe du premier groupe mais il a deux infinitifs et deux participes passés ([conjugaison](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/ficher_deuxieme-forme.html)).

Comment: @LPH : Je n'ai pas de réelle explicationn, mais j'ai complété ma réponse.

Comment: Ça tend vers une explication.

Comment: @LPH  Instinctivement je penche pour une abréviation dans le langage parlé par mimétisme avec "faire" ou "foutre" qui sont tous deux plus courts et cinglants qu'un verbe du 1er groupe comme "ficher". Mais il faudrait un.e linguiste pour répondre.

Answer (score 0):

> [...] utilisé comme euphémisme de *foutre* comme le montre la
> réfection du participe passé *fichu* sur *foutu* et celle de
> l'infinitif *fiche* sur *foutre*. ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/fiche/1))

Par analogie, les désinences sont [généralement](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/20377) conformes à l'usage pour l'infinitif et le participe passé d'un verbe du troisième groupe comme *foutre*. C'est là le sens-même de cette réfection...

> ◆ *Ficher* (XII<sup>e</sup> s.), ou plus courant *fiche* (au participe
> passé *fichu*, 1611), s'emploient familièrement pour « jeter avec plus
> ou moins de force, mettre », au propre et au figuré (*ficher qqn
> dehors*), et au sens de « donner » (1628) ; ce sémantisme se réalise
> dans des locutions comme ***ficher qqn dedans*** « l'induire en erreur
> » (1872). Dans ces emplois, c'est un euphémisme pour *foutre*. Comme
> ce dernier, le verbe a pris la valeur large de « faire » dans ***ne
> rien fiche***. [...] (DHLF/Rey)

Non seulement il y a réfection tel que discuté, mais développement parallèle du sens avec le verbe *foutre* même s'il peut y avoir concurrence avec la forme en *-er* dans certains cas. Ne pas présenter ces caractéristiques reviendrait à nier cette évolution parallèle et la réalité linguistique. Rien ni personne n'a un tel mandat.